# Undefined variable in $.each() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this class in javascript:

```
function rMotoristaList() {
}

rMotoristaList.prototype.permInsert = false;
rMotoristaList.prototype.permSelect = false;
rMotoristaList.prototype.permUpdate = false;
rMotoristaList.prototype.permDelete = false;

rMotoristaList.prototype.init = function() {
    // Pega as permissoes
    var perm = new cPermissao();
    this.permInsert = perm.verificaPermissao(ID_CAD_MOTORISTAS, "insert");
    this.permUpdate = perm.verificaPermissao(ID_CAD_MOTORISTAS, "update");
    this.permDelete = perm.verificaPermissao(ID_CAD_MOTORISTAS, "delete");

    if (this.permInsert == false) {
        $("#btn-add-novo").hide();
    }
};

rMotoristaList.prototype.renderGrid = function(data) {
    var html = "";

    // Faz o loop em todos os elementos retornados
    $.each(data,function(index, motorista) {
        if (this.permUpdate != false) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
};
```

The attrbitue `permUpdate` is `false`, but, when i compare him, inside of $.each(), don't work, i receive a `undefined`.

How can i get the value of `this.permUpdate` inside `$.each()`?

Comment: Inside the each callback, `this` refers to the current item in the loop not the class.  Halfway through writing and saw that @lgupta had posted the answer!  See that

Comment: Would it make more sense to have that if statment outside of the each? does the result of the conditional change on each iteration?

Comment: I recommend you reading something about closures in javascript and how the context for the function works... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200

Comment: @KevinB - +1, It sure would, what's the point of iterating if `this.permUpdate` is false and nothing happens anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an anonymous function `this` will not refer `rMotoristaList`. You can cache `this` and use it.

```
rMotoristaList.prototype.renderGrid = function(data) {
    var html = "",
        self = this;

    // Faz o loop em todos os elementos retornados
    $.each(data,function(index, motorista) {
        if (self.permUpdate != false) {
            //Do something
        }
};
```

Comment: You could have at least explain what have changed and why...like @sweetamylase.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside `$.each()` refers to the function context of the `.each()` and not the one in your code. What you can do is save your context outside of the `.each()` block, in JavaScript it's called a Closure, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures.

```
rMotoristaList.prototype.renderGrid = function(data) {
    var html = "";
    var that = this;
    // Faz o loop em todos os elementos retornados
    $.each(data,function(index, motorista) {
        if (that.permUpdate != false) {
        //Do something
        }
    }
```

}   ;

Answer (score 1):

There is also another approach, which might be somewhat better in situation like this...

```
rMotoristaList.prototype.renderGrid = function(data) {
    var html = "";

    // Faz o loop em todos os elementos retornados
    $.each(data,function(index, motorista) {
        if (this.permUpdate != false) {
            //Do something
        }
    }.bind(this)); // <-- Bind the function to the right context.
};
```

This way you are effectively saying, that this function should be executed with the context of rMotoristaList instance.